# how can force spacy to recognise "Mr. Smith" and "Mrs. Smith" as separate entities

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

How can I use spacy NER to find people in text and differentiate between Mr. Smith and Mrs. Smith as different people/named entities.

For example this identifies Smith and Smith as the same person:

```
text="Mr. Smith walked along the sea front. Mrs. Smith stayed at home."
basenlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = basenlp(text)
displacy.render(doc, style="ent")
```

I have tried to merge the tokens:

```
def compounds(doc):
    with doc.retokenize() as rt:
        for t in doc:
            if t.dep_=="compound":
                newt = Span(doc, t.i, t.head.i+1)
                rt.merge(newt)
    return doc

basenlp.add_pipe(compounds, "compounds", before="parser")
```

Same result with Smith and Smith

I try:

```
basenlp.add_pipe(compounds, "compounds", before="ner")
```

Now it does not find any entities.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it in the documentation under "expanding named entities":

https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching